# how to decide on 'auto' return type at compile time?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, lambda, c++17

In my naiveté, I thought this would compile. Alas not. I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community fully updated.

```
 namespace basic_problem {  
   auto msvc_does_not_compile = [] ( auto _string ) 
    -> std::vector< decltype(_string) >
  {
    return std::vector<decltype(_string)>{};
  };
}
```

Compilation attempt:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  auto vec = basic_problem::msvc_does_not_compile(std::string{});
  return 0 ;
}
```

Produces:

```
error C2514: 'std::vector<unknown-type,std::allocator<_Ty>>': class has no constructors
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=unknown-type
1>        ]
1>        program.cpp(97): note: see declaration of 'std::vector<unknown-
           type,std::allocator<_Ty>>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=unknown-type
1>        ]
```

I know I am hitting the boundaries here (perhaps). Any idea anyone? Is this doable at all in C++17? Basically I want to decide at runtime what type to return. Using no (obvious) templates. Just 'auto' and lambdas.

Of course C++ will not let me do it. But even if `I use if constexpr` msvc refuses to play the ball:

```
    auto msvc_does_not_compile_too = [](auto _string )
{
    using string_type = decltype(_string);

    if constexpr ( std::is_same<string_type, std::string>::value )
          return std::vector<std::string> ;
    else {
        return std::vector<std::wstring>;
    }
};
```

It strikes me as odd I can not decide at compiletime what type I will need at runtime. Using lambda and auto, that is.

Thanks ...

Comment: Your title is misleading. Return types must be known at compile time (and can be a polymorphic base class, `std::any`, or `std::variant` of course). In your example you are using a templated lambda. Concerning your question: [GCC 7.2.0 and Clang 5.0.0 compile your example without any issues](https://godbolt.org/g/FwNzYz).

Comment: Have you included `<vector>` and `<string>`? Including both my clang++ and g++ compile your first example; without `<string>` I get a similar error.

Comment: @max66: The [godbolt.org link included in my first comment](https://godbolt.org/g/FwNzYz) shows a similar error message as in the question for MSVC 19.

Comment: @Julius - I see... Well, I suppose a VC++ bug.

Comment: @Julius thanks of course, although: "misleading" or "a bit misleading" :) regarding the fact MSVC is (again) behind GCC and CLANG .. on implementing this lambda behaviour .. or so it seems?

Basically I do not understand why is title "mileading" .. I/we are doing auto type coercion but not before the lambda is returned from ... 

And it seems to me in a perfectly legal way using if constexpr version.

Comment: Do you actually need the trailing return type?

Comment: An argument used only for its type looks bad. What is your actual use case?

Comment: @n.m. please see the answer bellow ... that begins with the words: "Actual use case..."

Comment: Honestly, doesn't look like an answer to me at all.

Comment: By "fully updated" you mean 15.4.4 which is the current production version (a ``cl -Bv`` at the command-line returns 19.11.25547). There's a lot of work for ``if constexpr`` coming in the 15.5 update which is still in a [preview](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/11/15/msvc-conformance-improvements-in-visual-studio-2017-version-15-5/)

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn , are we going to debate what "fully updated" means? But for the 100% clarity yes, whatever VS2017 does when one does all the updates, that is what for me fully updated VS2017 MSVC means.

But, my "final" solution is even not using `if-constexpr` , I think it shows there are also few issues remaining in the MSVC UCRT. Or I am to be blamed for the wrong usage ;)

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn can you please let us know if this is a valid comparison here: https://godbolt.org/g/kekkNg

Is this ok  CL version ? I have tried /std:c++latest but still results are the same ...

Comment: "Version 19.10.25017.0" is the VS 2017 RTM compiler. A fully-updated compiler (15.5.6 is the latest production release right now) would report "Version 19.12.25835.0" for ``-Bv``.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn I have 19.12.25835.0 locally and yes things are much better , although one has to be careful and persuasive to convince CL to compile lambdas/if-constexpr/auto trio, with which clang has no issues whatsoever ...

Answer (score 2):

On godbolt.org's compiler explorer I find that [MSVC 2017 RTW 19.10.25017 complains about the simplest use of `constexpr if`](https://godbolt.org/g/6zEzM9) even with the flag `/std:c++latest`. However, [an official blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/05/10/c17-features-in-vs-2017-3/) claims support for `constexpr if` since VS 2017.3 [P2] (non-RTW). You should probably check that your version of MSVC handles those simple uses of `constexpr if` with the compilation flag `/std:c++latest`.

What you want to achieve works just fine <del>if plain function templates (and specializations if desired) are used</del> using simple overloading.

https://godbolt.org/g/BwuSPG

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace basic_problem {
    auto now_it_works(const std::string&) {
      return std::vector<std::string>{};
    }

    auto now_it_works(const std::wstring&) {
      return std::vector<std::wstring>{};
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  auto str = basic_problem::now_it_works(std::string{});
  static_assert(std::is_same<
    decltype(str), std::vector<std::string>
  >{}, "");

  auto wstr = basic_problem::now_it_works(std::wstring{});
  static_assert(std::is_same<
    decltype(wstr), std::vector<std::wstring>
  >{}, "");

  return 0;
}
```

As a side note, the working code illustrates that your title is misleading: The decision which type to return can not be made at runtime. Instead, the appropriate <del>template instantiation (or specialization)</del> overload is picked at compiletime.

Comment: thanks ... I have (perhaps not clearly) stated in my question  I would like to have solution based on lambda's and autos ...

Comment: Also (if  may) the core of the API (it seems quality of the API design is key) is very simple:

    auto command_line_data = create_command_line_data() ;

Where depending on the __wargv being null or not we return vector of wide strings or narrow strings. 

Solution to be all encapsulated in this one lambda ... Which we have for gcc and clang but not for msvc ...  And I would not like to go back to C++98 because MSVC can not compile legal C++17.



Again thanks for your involvement.

Comment: @DusanJovanovic: Have you considered `template<class T> auto command_line_data(const T& arg) { /* ... */ }`? I think that would provide the same "API".

Comment: Many thanks @Julius ... after few day of cogitations I manged to convince MSVC to allow me something that might be called simple. I am traveling tomorrow so I can't promise full answer with code (that I have finished sort of) before Sunday.

Answer (score 0):

Requirement: obtain vector representing the command line. Do it for all kind of executables that may have a command line in WIN 10.

But I am not here for people to do my "homework" I am here to check if I was right about using C++17 lambda+auto solution. It seemed simple robust and quick. And it turns out it is but not using msvc.

Actual use case operates on globals in MSVC + WIN situation

```
     #include <stdlib.h>
     #define _CRT_DECLARE_GLOBAL_VARIABLES_DIRECTLY
       auto   wargv_ = (__wargv);
       auto    argv_  = (__argv );
       auto    argc_  = (__argc ); 
   #undef _CRT_DECLARE_GLOBAL_VARIABLES_DIRECTLY
```

So far so good. But how we can tell when is wargv_ going to be null and when is argv_ going to be null? It seems wargv_ is always null, but one can not be certain.

So how do we encapsulate the core of the solution? With one lambda. Implementation is almost trivial. No overloads and no  templates. Just modern C++.

```
    auto command_line_data = [&]() {
      if ( wargv_ != nullptr ) {
        return std::vector<std::wstring>(wargv_, wargv_ + argc_);
      }
       else {
        return std::vector<std::string>(argv_, argv_ + argc_);
      }
};
```

Alas msvc can not take this ...  Thanks to @Julius for coding the gcc,clang, msvc comparison.

**Update -- "simple" and msvc friendly solution**

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
namespace {
#define _CRT_DECLARE_GLOBAL_VARIABLES_DIRECTLY

const auto  wargv_ = (__wargv);
const auto  argv_ = (__argv);
const auto  argc_ = (__argc);

#undef _CRT_DECLARE_GLOBAL_VARIABLES_DIRECTLY

namespace {

    using wvecT = std::vector<std::wstring>;
    using nvecT = std::vector<std::string >;

    // wargv_ !=  nullptr
    inline auto decide(std::true_type tt) {
        return wvecT{ wargv_, wargv_ + argc_ };
    }
    // wargv_ ==  nullptr
    inline auto decide( bool ft) {
        return nvecT{ argv_, argv_ + argc_ };
    }
}

auto cli_data = []() {
    return decide( 
        wargv_ != NULL 
        ? std::true_type{}
        : false
    );
};
} // nspace
```

I have no time right now for comparisons but yes decide() overloading and calling seems "funny", I think thanks to msvc run time ...

I am sure this can be optimized and made to look less like a stunt. But this works ..

**After the VS 15.5 Update (for me: 2017-12-05)**

Until yesterday (2017-12-06) this was not compiling under MSVC. But after VS 15.5 update it does.

```
    auto msvc_does_compile = [](auto _string)
     {
      using string_type = decltype(_string);
      return std::vector<string_type>{};
     };
   /*
    OK since VS 2017 15.5 update
   auto vec1 = msvc_does_compile( std::string{} );
   */
```

Adding explicit return type will still choke MSVC , but not gcc/clang as usual:

```
auto msvc_does_not_compile = [](auto _string)
    // explicit return type makes msvc not to compile
    -> std::vector< decltype(_string) >
  {
    using string_type = decltype(_string);
    return std::vector<string_type>{};
  };
```

And something of the same but simpler will be stopped even at the IDE editor stage:

```
    auto msvc_ide_does_not_allow = []( bool wide )
    {
       if (wide)
        return std::vector<std::string>();

        return std::vector<std::wstring>();
    };
```

Yes, again that troublesome pair gcc/clang has no problems with any of the above. Try which ever on-line ide you prefer to convince yourself...

EDIT 01FEB2018

My solution is wrong and it is a stunt. This is the best we can do for now:

```
#pragma once

#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include <tchar.h>

namespace stwish {

    using vector_tstring_type = std::vector<std::basic_string<_TCHAR> >;
    namespace {

        auto cli_data = []() {
            try {
                return
                    vector_tstring_type
                {
                    __targv,
                    (__targv ?
                    __targv + __argc :
                    __targv)
                };
            }
            catch (...) {
                throw std::runtime_error(__FUNCSIG__ " failed..." );
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This is the solution devised by one Mr Steve Wishnousky (Microsoft). Thanks Steve.

Comment: `wargv_pointer` cannot ever be a null pointer. The `if constexpr` will always take the same branch. It isn't clear what you are trying to do. This doesn't seem to answer the question anyway.

Comment: So? You are not checking the value of wargv_ (which I supose you can't do because it probably isn't a constant expression). You are checking its address (which is never null).

Comment: I know and I have changed the code ... I have no time right now to provide full implementation ... Perhaps you can?

Comment: I still have no idea what you are trying to do, but obviously MSVC is not able to compile `constexpr if` and some other C++17 constructs at all. Which is unfortunate but there's nothing we can do about it.

Comment: @n.m. Just to let you know I appreciate your involvement.